# .htaccess redirect exclude common search engines

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, seo

I am working on a website which the designer has asked for it to be a single page parallax design, I have done these in the past and always had the problems associated with a single page site particularly where SEO is concerned.

I am doing the site in wordpress and I have created the website pages as individual pages (for the most part) but I am now going through the process of loading all sub pages into the home page using jQuery and I wanted to ask about creating a .htaccess file to redirect anyone linking to the sub page from search results to the home page, BUT I want to exclude common search engines so they only log the content of the subpage as they shouldn't need to access the parallax page and I don't want search engines picking up on all the content in the main page.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: From an SEO perspective, showing humans something different from robots is a general bad idea.

Comment: Well my point is I want search engines to see the actual page that part of the site describes, where as if the search engine is redirected to the main part of the site it will log all the other pages at the same time.

Comment: To extend on what @briansol said above, this violates a lot of the search engine's policies. Google tends to place a ban on sites that don't provide the same content to users and bots. Just something to think about...

Comment: Ok guys I appreciate what your saying but your not providing any solution to the issue at hand in that if I have sub pages with content relevant to that sub page what do I do about it to make google etc see the content relevant to that page instead of a whole page with all page content on it.